# Pandas Conversion of datetime representation

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I got a Dataframe with a date column as a datetime64[ns] type in the following representation:

For 31st January 2016 it is: 2016-01-31

What I want is a representation looking like this:

For 31st January 2016: 1/31/2016

For 31st December 2016: 12/31/2016

The important thing is, that for all the months before october, the 0 at the beginning has to be dropped, that is just having one digit for the months up to september.

Comment: a representation in what output?

Comment: You can use `dt.strftime` and pass a format string but this will give you strings which are not that useful because once you convert from a datetime dtype then you can no longer filter using datetimes or perform arithmetic operations so you should just live with this is my opinion

Comment: @Boud You mean what datatype? If possible, datetime would be great.

Comment: @EdChum I tried strftime but I just found the option that would put me a 0 at the beginning for all the months before october. Can you give me the solution you have in mind? I will check if it's sufficient for my needs.

Comment: My point here is that fixing a display issue will give you a string which is not a useful dtype here if you're just planning on displaying the dates and not doing any filtering or arithmetic operations on them then using `dt.strftime` or splitting the day, month and year components and cobbling these into a string format of your choice is fine but it's counter-productive IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dt.strftime` to give you a string representation to swap the day month order if the dtype is already datetime:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-01-31', '2016-12-31']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

Out[3]:
        date
0 2016-01-31
1 2016-12-31

In [4]:
df['strftime'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df

Out[4]:
        date    strftime
0 2016-01-31  01/31/2016
1 2016-12-31  12/31/2016
```

However, as you don't want leading zeroes for day and month then you can just access the individual day, month, year components of the datetimes and cast these to str and add the separator yourself:

```
In [5]:
df['custom'] = df['date'].dt.month.astype(str) + '/' + df['date'].dt.day.astype(str) + '/' + df['date'].dt.year.astype(str)
df

Out[5]:
        date    strftime      custom
0 2016-01-31  01/31/2016   1/31/2016
1 2016-12-31  12/31/2016  12/31/2016
```

However, I advise against this, a datetime dtype allows easier filtering and arithmetic operations which are not easy when the dtype is a str so the column loses it's usefulness IMO

Comment: Thanks mate. This is absolutely fine for me, apparently. It's for a kaggle competition, that's why I'm asking for this strange representation but I definitely get your point!